# How to generate a specific country phone number on Postman?

Tags: python, random, postman

How to generate a specific country phone number (Specific Canadian city phone number who start with Quebec province Phone code) on Postman, because our API accept just Quebec province Phone code (514-XXX-XXXX, or 438-XXX-XXXX) I have this part of code in Python. I need just to format it to use it in Postman script.

```
def phn():
p=list('0000000000')
p[0] = str(random.randint(5,5))
for i in [1,2,6,7,8]:
    p[i] = str(random.randint(0,9))
for i in [3,4]:
    p[i] = str(random.randint(0,9))
if p[3]==p[4]==0:
    p[2]=str(random.randint(0,9))
else:
    p[2]=str(random.randint(4,4))
n = range(10)
if p[6]==p[7]==p[8]:
    n = (i for i in n if i!=p[6])
p[1] = str(random.randint(1,1))
p = ''.join(p)
return p[:3] + p[3:6] + p[6:]
```

Comment: What format is that?

Comment: python def and i want it in postman

Comment: So what does this "postman format" look like? It's not a simple string of 9 digits? (After some lateral thinking: "no it is not" is not the answer I am looking for.)

Comment: in Montreal city we use this format 514XXXXXXX or 438XXXXXXX so i need the 514 or 438 first and after is a random number

Comment: @esqew im trying to build an automated test running by newman so this phone number is unique. i have the code in python but i can not tranform it in postman

Comment: Postman has a JavaScript sandbox within the app, that will help  you to create whatever you like. So I guess the question is more about recreating the python code in JS. Postman is so much more than _simply a tool used for testing/documenting APIs_ 

Comment: @DannyDainton Seems I was mistaken, then - must have changed significantly since I last used it (which, admittedly, was a while ago). Nevertheless, my point still stands that I'd still expect to see some sort of attempt by the OP to get going in the right direction, which still isn't apparent.

Comment: I feel the same, even some level of effort/research would be better than none.  Postman is a living breathing software project, it can't stay the same forever 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a super quick and hacky way to create a random number in Postman and save it as a global variable, to use in other requests.

Using your prefix mentioned in the comments and using the `_.random()` function from Lodash:

```
pm.globals.set("phoneNumber", parseInt(517 + `${_.random(1000000, 9999999)}`));
```

As mentioned in a previous answer, you can use the random faker values in the sandbox but the format might not be what you need:

```
pm.globals.set("phoneNumber", pm.variables.replaceIn("{{$randomPhoneNumber}}"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Postman has its own sandbox scripts that make it easier to generate a random phone number, below is the link that should help you on the same:

https://learning.postman.com/docs/postman/scripts/postman-sandbox-api-reference/#phone-address-and-location

Also, would recommend you to go through this resource to understand this better :)
https://learning.postman.com/docs/postman/scripts/postman-sandbox/

Comment: I know this solution, but our API accept just somme Canadien phone format just 514xxxxxxx or 438xxxxxxx.